# Optimizing single vs multiple SQL queries on tree structure

Tags: mysql, sql, django, performance

Considering this table, modeling some hierarchical tree data using the [modified preorder tree traversal](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) method:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id INTEGER,
    parent_id INTEGER,
    tree_id INTEGER,
    level INTEGER,
    lft INTEGER,
    rght INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tree(id)
);
```

I have a function that needs to fetch all ancestors of all nodes in the tree. It uses a simple loop with the Django ORM, doing one query per row, spending ca 10s for 3000 rows.

Now, this made me curious - can this be optimized to be faster and use fewer queries?

My first thought was this single query:

```
SELECT D.id as descendant, A.id as ancestor 
FROM tree as D INNER JOIN tree as A ON 
 (A.tree_id = D.tree_id AND A.lft < D.lft AND D.rght < A.rght);
```

However, measuring the performance of this with real data showed that the single SQL query took roughly the same amount of time as the 3000 query method.

I can cache the result, so speed is no issue. I'm just wondering for curiosity's sake - Why is the single query using `join` not faster than performing 3000 individual queries? Are there any good ways to improve this query?

Comment: What to lft and rght represent?

Comment: "all ancestors of all nodes" - wouldn't that just be all nodes except the leaves? or did you mean "all ancestors of 1 node"?

Comment: @DanBracuk You can find a description in the link to the Django-MPTT implementation, but it's a variation of the [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Basically, nodes within a subtree can be described as `parent.lft < child.lft AND child.rght < parent.lft`.

Comment: What Engine are you using?  What is the cache size for that Engine?